# How to get List<String> all path from List<File>?

Tags: android

I am using this code to load the path of all file in the directory.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
    List<File> files = getListFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/"));
--------------------------------------------------------


private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
            } else {
                if(file.getName().endsWith(".csv")){
                    inFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
```

How to convert to use `List<File>` like `List<String>` to get path of file?

Comment: Can you not loop `List<File>` and get the path of file and add in a separate `List<String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get path from *File* you need to call *getAbsolutePath()* function or *getPath()* function on File object

since you have List iterate it and call that function

**Example**

```
     //mFiles is your List<Files>
    List<String>mPath=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(File f:mFiles){
        mPath.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```